# Baby's Ashes Scattering Question

Tags: moksha, death, rivers

Our Baby boy was born early at 25 weeks. He passed away at 32 weeks.

This happened in the US, and we cremated his body. I was advised by some people that babies/children's bodies usually is buried since they are not yet attached to their bodies unlike adults etc. But I did not want to leave a burial mark in a place where I am temporary visitor, so decided to cremate him.

Now, my question is what to do with the ashes/remains  (chithabhasmam) that the crematorium gave me.

I am unsure what rituals we have to do for baby' ashes. Do we do the Scattering (nimajjan) in some flowing water in the US itself? Crematorium folks said that I could do it discreetly as there are many people that do scattering in the US.
Or, is it more proper to take it back to India and do any rituals? Or, whichever way is okay as far as we are at peace with it?

I am being told conflicting opinion about this by different people, and that is why I thought of checking this here in this wonderful forum. I had also checked in reddit r/Hinduism and I was directed here.

Should there be any particular archanas that we need to do in the temple here after the scattering?

Forgive my ignorance about this.. and, Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am sorry your question got closed. For an answer to your question, I suggest the bharatiya vidwat parishad google group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bvparishat    I am positive you can find some help over there. The group has many Sanskrit scholars and experts in Hinduism.